# Closed interval in variation of a field

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation, mathematics, variational-calculus

Let's suppose that $\psi$ is a field so that $$\psi\in\Gamma^\infty(\pi):=\{\psi\in C^\infty(M,E)\ |\ \pi\circ\phi=I_M\}$$ where $E$ is a spacetime bundle over spacetime $M$ and $\pi : E\rightarrow M$ is projection map. Variation of the field is then defined as a family of smooth maps $$\hat{\psi} : M\times (-\epsilon, \epsilon)\rightarrow E$$ such that for every $x\in M$, $\hat{\psi}(x, 0) = \psi(x)$ provided that $0\in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

Why can't one take a closed interval $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]\subset\mathbb{R}$ in this definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This essentially boils down to that the notion of [differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) of a function in a point requires that the function is defined in an *open* neighborhood of that point.
2. If one wants discuss differentiability at a boundary point, one typically needs to impose additional technical assumptions, such as [one-sided limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) and [semi-differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability).
3. So if it is not otherwise essential to the construction, people usually stick to open neighborhoods to avoid the hassle.